# Error There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2012

I'm getting this error when trying to create a table with foreign key:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'TeamToPlayers' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FKey2'.

I don't understand why, there is a primary key in the table `TeamToPlayers`.

Here are the queries:

```
create table TeamToPlayers
(TeamName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PlayerName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  primary key(TeamName,PlayerName),
  CONSTRAINT FKey FOREIGN KEY (TeamName) REFERENCES Teams(TeamName)
)

create table Players
(PlayerName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
primary key(PlayerName),
CONSTRAINT FKey2 FOREIGN KEY (PlayerName) REFERENCES TeamToPlayers(PlayerName)
);
```

Comment: You've got the FK relationship backward. If you think about it, you'll see why this is happening. In order for Players to reference a key in TeamToPlayers, it needs to reference a whole key with a uniqueness constraint. However, if Players in TeamToPlayers references a key in Players, the whole key is the single attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table `TeamToPlayers` primary key consists of two fields - you must reference both as otherwise it's not a key. I think you may have your key the wrong way round - it should be on `TeamToPlayers` and referencing `Players` like so:

```
create table TeamToPlayers
(   
    TeamName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PlayerName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    primary key(TeamName,PlayerName),
    CONSTRAINT FKey FOREIGN KEY (TeamName) REFERENCES Teams(TeamName),
    CONSTRAINT FKey2 FOREIGN KEY (PlayerName) REFERENCES Players(PlayerName)
)

create table Players
(PlayerName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
primary key(PlayerName),
);
```

Comment: Not sure which of us got there first. +1

Comment: But i dont have TeamName in the players table- i want the TeamToPlayers table to show who is on a team. why do i need to reference both fields i i only use one?

Comment: Yes, that's all good, but you want a player in a team to be known about in your Players table, yes? That's why you have the FK to Players so that any player entered in TeamToPlayers **MUST** exist in Players first.

Comment: I think you you tried using a graphical design tool, your schema is wrong! Seeing it visually may help you. (Also, another tip: I wouldnt use the team name as a PK - if somebody changes the team name in the future it'll be messy). Use an identity and just put a unique constraint on the name. Not the question you asked, ...just saying.